# What happend when method with transaction invokes another method with transaction in sqlite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, transactions

I have an application in android which uses sqlite to persist the data.

is it correct if you invoke a method that starts a transaction from other method that starts another transaction like the example? what happend with the two transactions?

```
@Override
public void saveSurvApplied(MSurvey surv, MSApplied sa) {
    try {
        db.beginTransaction();
        SurveyManager surveyManager = ManagerFactory.getSurveyManager(ctx);
        surveyManager.saveSurveyState(surv); // it begins a transaction

        saDao.save(sa);
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Log.e(tag, "Error insertando las encuestas aplicadas", ex);
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
}
```

...

SurveyManagerImpl.java

```
@Override
public void saveSurveyState(MSurvey survey) {
    try {
        db.beginTransaction();

        for (MNode node : survey.getNodes()) {
            nodeDao.update(node);
            MItem[] items = node.getItems();
            if (items != null) {
                for (MItem item : items) {
                    itemDao.update(item);
                }
            }
        }
        surveyDao.update(survey);
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Log.e(tag, "Error actualizando la encuesta", ex);
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
}
```

could I provide some reference to learn what happens when you invoke nested transactions within sqlite?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction%28%29) says:

> Transactions can be nested. When the outer transaction is ended all of the work done in that transaction and all of the nested transactions will be committed or rolled back.